# Do I need to remove event listeners for FileReader() after I'm done with it?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I have a component with an `<input type='file'/>` to select and upload images to my Storage bucket.

I'm using `FileReader().readAsText(file);` which is asynchronous and I'm setting to listeners to the `onload` and `onerror` event.

> **From:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader
>
> Listen to these events using addEventListener() or by assigning an event listener to the oneventname property of this interface.

This runs everytime a user selects a file. I'm calculation an `md5` hash to use as the `fileName` in the storage.

```
if (newFile !== undefined && newFile !== null) {
  md5Hash = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {

    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event) => {
      console.log('md5 calculated!');
      const binary = event.target.result;
      resolve(md5(binary));
    };

    reader.onerror = (event) => {
      reject(event.target.result);
    };
    
    reader.readAsText(newFile);
    
  });
}
```

Do I need to bother to remove those listeners after I'm done with them? Is this a good practice or there's no point in doing that?

That code may run 5 or 6 times for different images that I'm uploading in the same page.

**NOTE:** It's a page to add blogPosts and the images for the posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no need. Eventually, the reader and the functions will have references only to each other¹ but nothing else will have references to either of them, and so they can all be garbage collected.

---

¹ And if the JavaScript engine optimizes those closures, which many do, only the `reader` has a reference to the functions, not the other way around, the way you've written them.

Comment: Woow !! That's a short nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your current example -

Why you care about `listeners` as it causes memory leaks

I will say **No**, you actually don't need to remove the `listener` as it is defined in your `Promise callback fn` and when that `fn` get executed, JavaScript Engine creates an execution context and defines it's environment variable then allocates memory. That memory get freed by garbage collector once your `fn` get executed and removed from `callstack` as references to location in the memory also limited to the `fn` so that get cleaned after your `fn`  executed.

However In general case I would say **Yes**, you should care about `listeners` it's a best practice for possible memory leaks issues.